# Redirect only if came from another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to set a `.htaccess` file to redirect to a specific URL only if the user came from outside. Once the request came from the same domain they must not be redirected. I'm not sure if it's possible?

```
#only from outside my_url.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^www.my_url.com$ my_url.com/home
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do add sample URLs in your question for better understanding of Question, thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I can't show the real domain

Comment: just samples will work always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`) since you'll need to examine the `Referer` HTTP request header in order to determine that the request "came from another domain".

Note that checking the `Referer` header is not 100% reliable, since the `Referer` can be suppressed by the originating website and manipulated by the end user. (But it's all you've got.)

This should also be a 302 (temporary) redirect, otherwise a 301 (permanent) redirect will be cached by the browser and the user will be redirected again when following the internal link on your website.

I will assume that direct requests (ie. when the user types the URL into the browser) or requests where the `Referer` is suppressed should not be redirected. ie. they are treated like internal links.

You can do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file, where `example.com` is *your* website domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^path/to/specific-url\.html$ /path/to/specific-url.html [R=302,L]
```

This states... for all requests, other than the `specific-url.html`, that are not directly typed into the browser (or `Referer` suppressed) and do not originate from your domain (`example.com`) then redirect to the `specific-url.html`.

Otherwise, any request for `specific-url.html` or originates from your domain, no redirect occurs.

If you've previously canonicalised the request (ie. HTTPS and www or non-www) then you could perhaps simplify the 2nd *condition*. Or updated this if you have other subdomains etc.

**WARNING:** This will badly affect SEO - if that is a concern - since search engines (eg. Googlebot) do not send a `Referer` header. You could potentially exclude bots by identifying the user-agent, however, you are then prone to being penalised for *cloaking* (serving different content to users and bots).

Comment: I've added an important warning regarding SEO.

Comment: ++ for the all important note on *cloaking*